# How many adjacent pairs do exist for an alphabet of size $l$, provided that the content of each pair is one or more adjacent letters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For instance, `("abc", "fd")` and `("abc", "ef")` are not valid pairs.
For "abc":

```
(a,  b)
(a,  bc)
(ab, c)
(b,  c)
```

I suppose the formula is $(l^3-l)/6, l\in\mathbb{N}$ by manual inference (up to $l=5$), but I have no references nor proof of that.

Comment: Sounds like you have to choose three natural numbers, $1≤s_1<s_2$,  $s_2+2≤s_3≤l$.  Where, of course, $s_1$ provides the start of the first block, $s_2$ the end of the first block, and $s_3$ the end of the second block.  Thus if $(s_1,s_2,s_3)=(2, 3, 7)$ and we have the ordinary alphabet, we'd be talking about $bc,defg$ as the "adjacent pair.  Should be a simple Stars and Bars count.

Comment: I can't understand the formula you are giving. For $l=5$, it gives an answer of $20$ pairs, which I can't find. Can you enumerate the pairs (if not for $l=5$, then for a smaller $l$ so that it is clearer what you are asking ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Sorry, ugly mistake on the question phrasing. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be a number string of $l$ consecutive numbers, $l \geq 2$

To count all ways to divide it into two contiguous parts, we need a divider, and need to choose a *start* and *finish* for the substring we examine

So take the "objects" including the divider as $l+1$, and  select any three "objects" (start, divider and finish) in all possible ways.

Thus the desired answer is simply $\dbinom{l+1}3$

eg for $l = 5,$ ans $= \dbinom63 = 20$

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

With the assumption $l \geq 2$, you start by noticing that given any string of length $a$, the number of non-empty substrings (contiguous pieces of the string) is $a(a+1)/2$. If you start your substring from the first letter, you have $a$ substrings possible, from second letter $a-1$ and so on. This sums to $a(a+1)/2$. Now consider your alphabet a string with the letter position indexed as $1, 2,...,l$

#### Main part

Of the two adjacent substrings you want, let us assume that the first letter of the first substring is at position $x$ where $1 \leq x \leq l - 1$ (because you do not want an empty substring for the second element of the pair). For a given $x$, you take any substring from the $l-x$ length alphabet right of the selected $x$ as the second element of the pair. This restricts the first substring of the pair you can have to only one specific substring (starting at $x$ till the beginning of the selected second element). Moreover, all possible pairs where the first element begins at position $x$ are covered when you take all the possible substrings of the $l-x$ portion of the alphabet on the right of $x$.

All we have left, is to calculate the following sum to get your answer:
$$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{l-1}\frac{(l - x)(l -x + 1)}{2}$$
$$=\sum\limits_{x=1}^{l-1}\frac{l^2-2lx+l-x+x^2}{2}$$

This evaluates to $(l^3-l)/6$ as you want.